# Aligning text side by side in different divs

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm new to web design and I'm making a website as a project for my friend. I've got two divs with different content in each div, one for the main content and one for news and other things which I want at the side.

I've sorted the content div out and thats fine its where I want it. But when I go to float the news div right it goes from under the content div (Inside the wrapper div still) to out side the wrapper div but to where I want it. (I know this because for now I've got a blue border round so I can make sure everything is inside where I want it to be.)

Heres my code and css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Bake Away</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="img/logo.png">
<img src="img/ad_bar.png">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navBar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Responsibility</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Working With Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="images">
<img src="img/scroll_1.png">
</div>
<div id="content">
<span>Welcome to the Bake Away Bakery, here you can find out about
all the wonderful things we bake. How you can place orders, who we
bake for, where we're based, apply for jobs and contact head office.</span>
</div>
<div id="news">
<h3>Latest news:</h3>
<span>We've just started our new line of cakes that should
hit the shelves by Monday.</span>
<span class="read">Read More</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
background-color:#E6E6E6;
font-family:consolas;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:normal;
text-align:center;
}
img{
margin-top:5px;
margin-right:15px;
}   
#wrapper{
width:1000px;
border:1px solid blue;
margin:3px;
margin-left:13px;
text-align:left;
}
#navBar{
color:white;
margin:2px;
margin-right:43px;
height:50px;
font-size:25px;
font-weight:bold;
float:center;
text-align:center;
}
#navBar ul{
list-style-type:none;
}
#navBar li{
display:inline;
}
#navBar a{
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#BDBDBD;
color:black;
padding:2px;
}
#navBar a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
background-color:#FE2E2E;
color:white;
}
#images img{
margin-left:50px;
}
#content{
width:450px;
margin-left:7px;
margin-bottom:3px;
font-size:16px;
}
#news{
width:300px;
}
```

Comment: display:inline-block; will be your best bet I would say to line them up next to each other. Else you need to use the float:left; to get them all inline.

Comment: There's no CSS in your question, please add CSS or create a fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can add `display: inline-block;`, Simple as hell ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block` to the following css:

```
#navBar {
    color:white;
    margin:2px;
    margin-right:43px;
    height:50px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:center;      // there is nothing like this. Wrong text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
}
#images img {
    margin-left:50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#content {
    width:450px;
    margin-left:7px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    font-size:16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#news {
    width:300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S9EtU/)

Comment: That still doesn't keep it inside the blue line.

Comment: @user2639366 is that about top 2 images?

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` is how you do it.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32384693)